# VHDL case insensitivity

Tags: vhdl, case-insensitive

I have seen capital letters of VHDL key words being used, probably for the coding style reason, such as IF - THEN - ELEIF - ELSE - END IF; LIBRARY IEEE; USE numeric_std.ALL; However, it says VHDL "language is , for the most part, NOT case sensitive". Therefore, I would assume that all the key words listed above could be written using small case letters as well.

Does anybody have a good knowledge on the few exceptions that the key words need to be (or have to be) in capital letters?

Comment: That "good knowledge" is the LRM.

Comment: Some prefer to write keywords in caps. Some prefer to write them in small cases. The language doesn't care. Whatever you do, stick to one and remain consistent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know the only things in VHDL that are case-sensitive are *literals* (fixed values in your code) of type `character` and `string`. So, for example, the `std_logic` type is an *enumeration type* of `character`s. With any `character` an upper-case letter is different to a lower-case letter. So, for example, `'X'` and `'x'` are different characters. So, if you are assigning an `'X'` to something of type `std_logic`, for example, then you must use an upper-case `'X'` not a lower-case `'x'`, because that is how the `std_logic` type is defined. eg:

```
my_signal <= 'X';
```

is OK but

```
my_signal <= 'x';
```

is not, because `'x'` is not a valid `std_logic` value.

So, basically, *VHDL is not case sensitive*. It just seems like it might be when you are dealing with `character`s (and `string`s, which are just arrays of `character`s). Any language that could not distinguish between a lower-case and an upper-case letter would be a strange one indeed.

Comment: For added confusion, extended identifiers are case sensitive. `\bus\ ` and `\BUS\ ` are different identifiers (from VHDL LRM)

Comment: I know another situation is 'Z', which means tri state. You can't use 'z' instead of 'Z'. But, what does 'z' and 'x' mean if I mistakenly use it?

Comment: In: TYPE enum IS (idle, fill, heat, wash, drain) statement, does "idle, fill, heat, wash, drain" case sensitive?

Comment: @Cindy - no, they are not strings, hence not case sensitive.